# gitでのブランチを置き換える方法について

Tags: git

例えば、以下のような状態があったとして、現在は、Branch Aで作業しているとします。これを main origin/mainにする方法はありますか？

```
----〇----〇----〇----〇----〇----〇----● Branch A
 └─〇----★main origin/main
```

※〇はpushしたタイミングで、●は現在の作業場所です。

★に含まれる変更点ついては、マージやチェリーピックなどの必要はなく、ここで放置で良い状態です。

ツールは、

- Git Extensions 3.5.4.12724
  を使っています。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ブランチ名を置き換えたいという事でしょうか？ (今 main になっているブランチは別の名前に置き換える？) また、origin/main はリモートリポジトリとして別の誰かが参照していたりしますか？

Comment: 不要なコミットは除いたうえで、main に Branch A をマージ等で取り込む方が分かりやすそうかなと個人的には思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。「ブランチ名を置き換えたいという事でしょうか？ 」です。origin/main は今のところ別の人は見ていないですが、git hub上にはあります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
$ git checkout main
```

マージもするなら、

```sh
$ git checkout main
$ git merge branchA
```

これが普通のやり方かと思います。もしマージしたくなくて、リネームだけがやりたいなら、

```
$ git branch -m main tmp
$ git branch -m branchA main
```

「mainは放置でいい」といっても、branchAをmainにリネームするなら重複することになるので、放置する用の名前(この場合はtmp)が必要です。branchAという名前のブランチはなくなるので、やるなら自己責任でお願いします。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。「branchAという名前のブランチはなくなる」は後から参照することもできなくなるという認識であってますよね。

Comment: 参照することができなくなるというよりは、branchAがmainという名前になるだけですね。ちなみに元々あったmainはtmpになるのでtmpを参照できます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。反応が遅くなりすみません。

Answer (score 1):

対応後が次のようなイメージであるならば、

```
----〇----〇----〇----〇----〇----〇----● main origin/main
 └─〇----〇 old_main
```

次の操作で行えます:

```
# 作業ディレクトリに branch-a をチェックアウト
git checkout branch-a
# 現在の main ブランチ名をリネーム
git branch -m main old_main
# 現在チェックアウトしているブランチの名前(branch-a)を main に変更
git branch -m main
# 現在チェックアウトしているブランチ(branch-a 改め main)を GitHub 上の main ブランチに上書き
git push -f -u origin HEAD
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。「後から参照できるようなニュアンスにも聞こえます」はおっしゃる通りで、見ることは出来るようにしておきたいと思っています。（リネームしないと残らないのですね）

Comment: 旧 `main` ブランチを保持する手順で更新しました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。反応が遅くなりすみません。